# How do I deactivate the automatic design changes in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

When importing stencils (drag&drop) they always get colored and overpainted with the currently selected standard style. This is undone by selecting the drop down in shape styles and clicking "remove design".

This is very tedious however since it needs to be repeated for each stencil imported, so **where do I find the option to deactivate this automatic style change upon import ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after some searching:

**Go to Design Tab -> click on the arrow to open the Dropdown for all the Designs -> Deselect the checkmark "Apply design on new shapes" (actual text might differ due to me translating it from german)**